# Flutter Firestore date

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I know this is duplication but since I haven't been able to find correct way so please don't mark this as duplicate. 
I would like to set date type correctly to `Firestore` in flutter. I tried `DateTime.now()` but when I retrieve it error says

> Unsupported value: FIRTimestamp: seconds=1533950401 nanoseconds=81000000> of type FIRTimestamp

and app will crash. Also I tried `millisecondsSinceEpoch`, `microsecondsSinceEpoch`, `toUtc` but Firestore recognize those as number not timestamp. I used `intl` package and formatted like `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm` but it was recognized as String. 
Does anyone know how to set timestamp correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Answer (score 3):

The Firestore database only has a Timestamp field record. The following worked and saved the timestamp properly.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION_NAME').add({
   'weight': someDoubleValue,
   'when': DateTime.now(),
});
```

This is with

```
firebase_core: ^0.2.5
cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2
```