# How does FlutterFire Cloud FireStore handle Dart DateTime and enum?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-file

I can't find any data type reference guide that explains how Flutter (Dart) 'DateTime' and 'enum' data types should be represented in the Map structure passed to a FlutterFire FireStore  add/update document call.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61138375/14434426) to another question about enums:

Flutter is able to generate JSON serialization code. It references the package json_annotation. It contains also support for enum serialization. So all you need is to use this tool and annotate your enum values with @JsonValue.

From the code docs:

```
An annotation is used to specify how an enum value is serialized.
```

For time objects the answer is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249441/14434426):

Use

```
FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```